# Is there a reserved JavaScript constant for a "max" integer value?

Tags: javascript, integer, comparison, max

If I have a piece of logic like this

```
var a = 9999999;
while(!c)
{
    if(b < a)
    {
       a = b;
    }
}
```

is there a cleaner way to set the initial value of a?  I'm well aware that there are minimum functions I could use, but there are other more complicated / customized needs for having a very large starting value.

I am also aware that this logic could be rewritten so that on the first loop a will always = b, then on following loops you'll do the check.

This is more of a mere curiosity since a true max value seems like something a weakly typed variable language would have.  Is there any way in JavaScript to set a variable to a value while will ALWAYS be larger than what it's compared to?

Comment: Simple to find in a google search for `javascript maximum integer`. [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) At least try searching before asking

Comment: I'm not looking for the maximum integer (which as you said is common knowledge), I'm looking for a constant that will always evaluate to true when compared with any integer.  So `someConstant > someInteger` will always be true.  JordanHendrix's answer has what I'm looking for.

Comment: Irregardless a few minutes of searching would have gotten you what you wanted. My comment and search was directly related to title of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Infinity` and `-Infinity`:

[MDN Docs on Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `MAX_VALUE` which is equal to `1.7976931348623157e+308`

```
var a = Number.MAX_VALUE;
while(!c)
{
    if(b < a)
    {
       a = b;
    }
}
```

Read [max_value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE)